# Esempi di uso del verbo "scarrucolare"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Nel romanzo *Pane e tempesta* di Stefano Benni ho letto:

> Non fu facile girare la rotella dei numeri. Il dito vigoroso di Piombino si sostituì a quello delicato di Alice e lottò contro anni di ruggine. I numeri **scarrucolavano** gemendo uno dopo l'altro.

Il testo fa riferimento a un vecchio telefono. Non capivo bene il significato di "scarrucolare" in questo passaggio, perciò ho cercato questo verbo nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scarrucolare) e ho trovato questa definizione:

> Scorrere velocemente e liberamente, della fune o della catena sulla girella della carrucola, o anche della girella stessa.

Quindi, se ho capito bene, questo termine nel brano significa che i numeri giravano sulla rotella del telefono.

Mi è sembrato un verbo molto curioso e mi piacerebbe averne alcuni esempi di uso. Ho cercato un po' su Google, ma ho trovato soltanto cose molto strambe.

Comment: Andando a intuito, nell'uso del verbo, oltre al movimento rotatorio, ci vedo anche una certa fatica, magari un cigolio visto che il disco del telefono è arrugginito (cf. anche “gemendo”). Lo so che la definizione parla di uno scorrere veloce e libero, ma a orecchio percepisco questo senso.

Answer (score 2):

È un verbo particolarmente usato in ambito marinaresco, ma più spesso nel significato 2 della [voce](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scarrucolare), che qui riporto:

> Uscire dalla gola di una carrucola, per es. dei fili aerei di veicoli elettrici (filobus, ecc.), dei nastri per l’apertura e la chiusura di persiane avvolgibili, ecc.

Per esempio, nelle barche a vela le corde di manovra delle vele, le [*scotte*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scotta1/), scorrono in particolari pulegge,
 i [*bozzelli*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bozzello/). Se una scotta o, più in generale, una [*cima*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cima/) (significato 4) esce da un bozzello, magari bloccandosi incastrata, si dice che è scarrucolata.

Cercando *scarrucolare* con Google è probabile che tu abbia trovato più esempi del significato 2 che dell'1, e se erano tratti da discorsi ricchi di termini marinareschi, non mi meraviglio che tu li abbia trovati strambi!

Comment: Non ricordo aver letto niente che abbia a che vedere con l'ambito marinaresco, ma piuttosto cose come, per esempio, [questa](https://books.google.es/books?id=-WGRBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT83&lpg=PT83&dq=scarrucolava&source=bl&ots=_KD623-clc&sig=Il44xfhlWulDCXq3Di2rflegynU&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5t9WV0qvWAhWCXBQKHcpfDosQ6AEIGTAG#v=onepage&q=scarrucolava&f=false): "La signora Kùcscina **scarrucolava** uno sull'altro i suoi interrogativi con affettata negligenza, e non aspettava risposta...".

Comment: @Charo In effetti in quel caso si tratterebbe del significato 1, con senso figurato. Però, mentre nel primo esempio da te riportato i numeri scarrucolano faticosamente, qui direi che lo scarrucolare dà l'idea di un flusso inarrestabile. In ogni caso, al di fuori dell'ambito tecnico, _scarrucolare_ è un verbo estrememamente raro, e qualunque uso può sembrare strano.